# Adding two queries to a table model

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I have to add two queries to a table model so that it shows up on the table. It is a program doing prediction on soccer (EPL to be precise) and I need to display ALL results for the team when they are playing both home, and away. the first query is to get all the games where they play home, the second query is when they play away. Here is the code:

```
public void showResultsTotalTeam(){
    deleteAllRows(dTableModel); // deleta all rows in the table
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection.conn_url, connection.conn_user, connection.conn_pass);// connect to database server
        Statement sqlState = conn.createStatement();// create statement for sql
        String selectStuff = "SELECT games_team1, games_team2, games_winner, games_draw, games_team1_score, games_team2_score, games_month, games_day FROM games WHERE games_team1 = '" + cbxTeam1.getSelectedItem() + "'";// ststement for MySQL
        rows = sqlState.executeQuery(selectStuff);  // execute statement
        String selectStuff2 = "SELECT games_team1, games_team2, games_winner, games_draw, games_team1_score, games_team2_score, games_month, games_day FROM games WHERE games_team2 = '" + cbxTeam1.getSelectedItem() + "'";// ststement for MySQL

        rows2 = sqlState.executeQuery(selectStuff); // execute statement
        Object[] tempRow;// create object array to store queried results
        Object[] tempRow2;

        while(rows.next()){ // while there are still values to be seen to
            tempRow = new Object[]{rows.getString(1), rows.getString(2), rows.getString(3), rows.getString(4), rows.getString(5), rows.getString(6), rows.getString(7), rows.getString(8)};// add data to array
            tempRow2 = new Object[]{rows2.getString(1), rows2.getString(2), rows2.getString(3), rows2.getString(4), rows2.getString(5), rows2.getString(6), rows2.getString(7), rows2.getString(8)};
            dTableModel.addRow(tempRow); // add array to table model
            dTableModel.addRow(tempRow2);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now this code does not work and nothing shows up at all.

Please help? Any advice would be great.

Comment: `now this code does not work` - what does that mean? Did you do any basic debugging, like at a display statement to see the values returned from the query? I suggest you keep your code simple and do one query at a time. Update the model after each query.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the number of rows == number of rows2 then you may encounter trouble when you are iterating through `rows.next`

Also suggest you iterate do you code in two distinct blocks i.e one for `rows` and one for `rows2`

**Edit**

This could also be done with one query

```
SELECT games_team1, games_team2, games_winner, games_draw, games_team1_score, 
games_team2_score, games_month, games_day FROM games 
WHERE games_team1 = '" + cbxTeam1.getSelectedItem() + "' " 
or games_team2 = '" + cbxTeam1.getSelectedItem() + "' "
```

Comment: But then I cannot append it to the table model? That's what I tried first. The rows are the same in length.

Comment: why do you even bother with two queries.  see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You haven't loaded thr driver class

```
Class.forName("Driver Class Name");
```

And you haven't closed anything. Connecton & ResultSet

Comment: You don't have to declare driver name in Java 7